# cpanel full backup via ssh, but logged as cpanel user

Tags: ssh, backup, cpanel

it is possibile to save a FULL backup of cpanel, while logged via SSH as cpanel user (not root user)

via cpanel api it is possibile, but only with root access

is there another way? it should be possibile, as it is for the user logged in cpanel normally...

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to generate the full backup of your cpanel then you can save it in your local disc via ssh command.

like this

`scp -P 7822 /c/users/mh/desktop/Email/Migration/xyz.zip xyz@70.32.31.17:/home/xyz/xyz.com.pk/`

Answer (score -1):

You cannot save a full backup of a cpanel account using ssh as cpanel user. As you know, pkgacct script is used to take a full account backup and this command is not available for non root users. You can read more about this from below cpanel forum:
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/backup-pkgacct-as-non-root-user.551071/